# Attempting to reading Serilog config from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, json, serilog

I'm converting a c# project to .Net Core (not ASP.Net core) and cannot get the examples posted on the Serilog site to compile. I must be missing something simple. I'm trying to read the Serilog config from appsettings.json. Below is the code from the site:

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

The problem I'm having is that `.Build()` returns a 
`Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot`. `ReadFrom.Configuration()` is expecting a `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` object. 
I tried using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder()` but there is no `.AddJsonFile()`. Has anyone else used this code and can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have installed an old version of *Serilog.Settings.Configuration* or some other package - any reference you see to `Microsoft.Framework.*` is an old pre-1.0 package that won't work with the current .NET Core bits.

In particular, make sure no packages are referencing *Microsoft.Framework.Configuration*, and upgrade any that do.